# SVG + Chrome + filter + negative scale

Tags: google-chrome, svg, svg-filters

I've found Google Chrome is not displaying SVG elements which have *both* a negative scale *and* a filter (e.g. Gaussian blur). Is this a bug?

Minimum non-working example:

```
<filter id="blur-norm">
    <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="1 3" />
</filter>
<g id="norms" transform="scale(-0.5)">
    <rect x="-40" y="-50" width="100" height="100" fill="#50aea9" stroke="#355270" stroke-width="5" />
</g>
```

Comparing this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fv1jz0fq/1/) in

- Firefox 32 / Win7: element is visible and blurred
- Chrome 37 / Win7: element is not visible

In chrome, setting the scale to be a positive number will make the element appear (although incorrectly scaled); alternatively, removing the filter reference will make the element appear (although not blurred).

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a Blink bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it was reported a few days ago.

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409602

Comment: Chromium contributors seem to have created a fix, but it looks like it won't be released until v39.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get Chrome to display any filters until I removed the  out of the head section then presto, got all filters displayed.

Comment: Welcome. Thanks for the tip, though this would be better posted as a comment (and is likely to be deleted in the future.)

Comment: @mins: maybe the user sounds insecure, but the answer itself seems to be helpful.

Comment: @min: this question popped up for review. While the accepted answer tells us that it's a bug, this answer actually attempts to provide a solution via a workaround. I don't see any reason to delete this.

Comment: The bug as described by the accepted answer has now been fixed—Chrome 42 is able to correctly render the JSFiddle linked in my question. So no workaround should be necessary any more. I guess this kind of advice might be useful if a related bug crops up in the future, though.